# How to display count of a subgroup with ggplotly() tooltip = "text" in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, ggplotly

does anyone know how I could display the count per group within the tooltip with `ggplotly()` using `grom_bar`, that shows already at least visually how many times `Very Good` `cut` and `Colour` `E` occured together in df? How should I address the count in the `text` aesthetics, in this case? And, I already know that if I change `ggplotly(p, tooltip = "all")` I see the count. I also checked this link [How to control "count" in tooltip for ggplotly with filled bar plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505903/how-to-control-count-in-tooltip-for-ggplotly-with-filled-bar-plot-in-r)    .  But I would like to have the flexibility of `text` so I could customize the tip. 
Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data("diamonds")
p = ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut,   fill = as.factor(color), 
                   text = paste0("Cut: ", cut,"<br>Count: ", ???, "<br>Color: ",color, "<br>Count: ", ???))
      ) + 
geom_bar()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you really want to show, but maybe you can calculate the values before the plot.

```
p <- diamonds %>% 
  count(cut, color) %>% 
  add_count(cut, wt = n, name = "total") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = n, fill = as.factor(color),
             text = paste0("Cut: ", cut, "<br>Count: ", total, "<br>Color: ", color, "<br>Count:  ", n))) +
  geom_col()
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

Comment: Thank you! In the end I used the same approach but with group_by() and summarise()  `diamonds %>% group_by(cut,color) %>% summarise(count = n()) ..` I was only wondering if the count of geom_bar was accesible in the tooltip, without extra lines of code, which would have been more visible if I had typed it `ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut,   fill = as.factor(color), =  paste0("Cut: ", cut,"<br>Count: "  ???,  "<br>Color: ",color, "<br>Count:  ",???))` - the question marks outside the quotes. My mistake.

Comment: ```ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = color, text = paste0("Count: ",..count..))) + 
  geom_bar()``` this works